# Python/Arduino: PySerial, Matplotlib, numpy; Raspbian

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**EDIT: I am receiving the following error message:*
"Error retrieving accessibility bus address: or.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files"

I wrote code for the PC platform using Python and it works just fine. I was looking to have this program run on a rasberry pi connected to a monitor.

I installed Raspbian and all of the libraries for the above needed functions.

The code is as follows:

```
############################################################
# Visualizing data from the Arduino serial monotor         #
# and creating a graph in a nice format. Later work will   #
# look into outputting this to a Android device            #
############################################################
############################################################

############################################################
############################################################

#Becuase we can always use more time
import time

#Inport the fancy plotting library 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Inport the serial library
import serial

#We want to do array math so we need Numpy
import numpy

#We also want to draw things so we need drawnow and
#everything that comes with it
from drawnow import *


############################################################
############################################################

#Creating an array to hold data for plotting. See several
#lines below for more information

tempArray = []
pressureArray = []
altitudeArray = []

#The object that is created to interact with the Serial Port
arduinoSerialInput = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 230400)

time.sleep(3)

#Here we set the definition oto look for interactive mode
#and plot live data
plt.ion()

############################################################
############################################################

clippingCounter = 0

#Here we define a function to make a plot, or figure of
#the data aquired

def plotTempData():

    plt.ylim(150,320)
    plt.title('Plots from data of the BMP Sensor')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Tempature')
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(tempArray, 'ro-', label='Degrees K', linewidth=2)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

    #plt2 = plt.twinx()
    #plt2.plot(pressureArray, 'bx-')

def plotPresData():

    #plt.ylim(260,320)
    plt.title('Plots from data of the BMP Sensor')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Pressure')
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(pressureArray, 'bo-', label='Pascals', linewidth=2)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.plot(pressureArray, 'bo-')
    plt.show()

############################################################
############################################################

while (1==1):
    #First things first, lets wait for data prior to reading
    if (arduinoSerialInput.inWaiting()>0):
        myArduinoData = arduinoSerialInput.readline()
#        print myArduinoData -Line commented out, see below

#The arduino should be set up to proovide one string of data
#from here we will seperate that one string into two or more
#to make it easier to plot

        #This will create an array seperated by the comma
        #we specified in the Arduino IDE aasign it to a
        #variable of our choice and convert the string
        #back into a number using the float command
        dataArray = myArduinoData.split(',')
        temp =  float(dataArray[0])
        pressure = float(dataArray[1])

        #Used to test the printing of values to output
        #print temp, " , ", pressure, " , ", altitude

#We need to create an array to to hold the values in question
#Looking at the top, you will see the empty array we need to
#create that will hold the values we need to plot
        tempArray.append(temp)
        pressureArray.append(pressure)

        plt.figure(1)
        drawnow(plotTempData)
        plt.pause(.000001)

        #plt.figure(2)
        drawnow(plotPresData)
        plt.pause(.000001)



#We want to clip some data off since the graph keeps
#expanding and too many points are building up.
        clippingCounter = clippingCounter + 1
        if(clippingCounter>50):
          tempArray.pop(0)
          pressureArray.pop(0)



############################################################
############################################################
```

Comment: ive found with arduino i usually need to sleep for a few seconds after opening the port (that may or may not actually be your issue)

Comment: Nope, that won't do it, but thanks. I imported time > import time , I then used the "time.sleep(3)" function directly below the arduinoSerialInput = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 230400) command. Still nothing at the output shell

Comment: Have you tried running your code from the commandline - you might see the error then

Comment: Nice. I was able to find an error messege but I can't find any amenable Google searches to resolve it. The error messege is as follows: "Error retrieving accessibility bus address: or.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files"

Comment: I just upgraded to the new Pi3 and at the terminal window I ran the code as mentioned above. I get no error message now. I'm gunna try another OS besides Raspbian for now.

Comment: My guess is that matplotlib is trying to use a gtk backend o display your graph, and there is something wrong with your gtk installation. Could you check what  matplotlib.get_backend() returns ?

Comment: @PierreRust Thanks. Looks like we found an error. " 'Module' object has no attribute 'backend' " After googling that I installed glade (using sudo apt-get) and libgtk2.0-dev. I still get the same error after the installations.

Comment: hum, you definitely have a problem with your installations if matplotlib has no backend. I'd try installaing everything a virtualenv with pip install, but it's going to be difficult to diagnose remotely...

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned is I believe an issue with 'at-spi2-core' module.  The problem seems fixed on Ubuntu version 2.9.90-0ubuntu2, have you tried to upgrade the 'at-spi2-core' module? Alternatively forcing it to be enabled might solve your issue.

Information on ensuring the SPI is enabled is here :
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/08/enabling-the-spi-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Would have added this in a comment as I am not 100% on this but I don't have the rep for that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the recommendation does not work however. Btw, I am using Raspbian Jessie, not Ubuntu. I have enabled the SPI interface and now I get no error message at all when running in either the Python IDE or the terminal. The terminal just hangs now and doesn't report any error. Unfortunately, I don not know what to do.

Comment: Glad enabling SPI helped but sorry to hear you are still having issues.  I mentioned the Ubuntu patch to show the problem is resolved upstream (albeit on a different distro), however it seems you have a different issue now anyway.  Good luck, sorry I can't help further.